# how to get data from a google spreadsheet from flowxo in c#

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, google-sheets, webhooks

I'm trying my best to make a free database I can store my users username and passwords in (hashed ofc) and I used a flowxo webhook to add the data from my c# application to the spreadsheet to make the account but I have no way to allow users to log in so I need to be able to scan the spreadsheet for the data provided how would I go about doing this? A link to flowxo: https://flowxo.com/

```
        string user = username.Text;
        string pass = Password.Password;
        string name = anameb.Text;
        string webhook = "Webhook was here";
        var wbc = new WebClient();
        var data = new NameValueCollection();

        string password = pass; // sample password
        string salt = Crypto.GenerateSalt(); // salt key
        password = password;
        string hashedPassword = Crypto.HashPassword(password);


        data["email"] = user;
        data["password"] = hashedPassword;
        data["name"] = name;
        create.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        wbc.UploadValues(webhook, data);
```

Comment: Hi there @Rj1234 ! Could you please share the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you are using so that we can better help you? And please remember to remove or anonymize any private information.

Comment: Sure @Jacques-Guzel Heron